# How to use business rules engine in Python with async support?

Tags: python, async-await, rule-engine, business-rules

I want to integrate a Python library in a larger system that allows to specify a set of business rules with conditions and actions. [Business Rule Engine](https://pypi.org/project/business-rule-engine/) library matches all the requirements with an issue being not able to support async functions in conditions or actions. Other libraries I evaluated appear not to support async methods.

What am I missing here? I can contemplate that context required for conditions can be pre-fetched and passed to the engine beforehand, but what about actions? e.g. requesting a service to send an email.

Please suggest another lib or enlighten me.